# Installing packages from pip3

Tags: windows, installation

(windows 10) Why when I try to download a package from pip3 I get this message: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your command line as admin.

1. Click the Start icon and click in the Search box.
2. Type cmd into the search box. You will see the cmd (Command Prompt) in the search window.
3. Hover the mouse over the cmd program and right-click.
4. Select "Run as administrator".

After that run you pip commands:

```
python -m pip install ...
```

Comment: Ok thank you it worked

Comment: I see you're new here at Stack Overflow. If the answer solved your problem you can mark it as the correct answer.